# WPF LiveChart: How to remove default Axis label values

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I am trying to plot LineSeries with WPF LiveChart.

The YAxis displays the default label values of -0.2 to 0.2 and doesn't update to the real data values.

**XAML**

```xaml
 <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding LineSeriesCollection}" 
                            LegendLocation="Right" AxisY="{Binding LineAxisYCollection}" >

       <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Date" LabelFormatter="{Binding LineXFormatter}"/>
       </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>

 </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

**C#**

```c#
 public void Plot()
 {

            var axis = new Axis
            {
                Foreground = Converters.Colors.GREEN,
                Position = AxisPosition.LeftBottom,
                Unit = 1,
                MinValue = 0
            };
            var series = new LineSeries
            {
                Stroke = Converters.Colors.GREEN,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush() { Opacity = 0.15, Color = Converters.Colors.GREEN.Color },
                PointForeground = Converters.Colors.GREEN,
                Title = "Bills"
            };
            series.Values = new ChartValues<ObservableDateModel>
            {
                new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now, 2),
                new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 5),
                new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), 6),
                new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), 8),
                new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), 5),
                new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5), 5),
                new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(6), 5)
            };
            LineSeriesCollection.Add(series);
            LineAxisYCollection.Add(axis);
 }
 public SeriesCollection LineSeriesCollection { get; set; }
 public AxesCollection LineAxisYCollection { get; set; }



public class ObservableDateModel : NotificationObject
{
        public ObservableDateModel(DateTime date, double value)
        {
            Date = date;
            Value = value;
        }

        private double _value;

        public double Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private DateTime _date;

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return _date; }
            set { _date = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

}
```

When I clear the chart axis, the default label values go away but it throws Axis.cs not found exception.

I also noticed that if I do not create instances of `LineSeriesCollection` and  `LineAxisYCollection` in the constructor, it throws Chart.cs not found exception.

I want to remove the default label values.

The image below shows a data value of 21 but the chart y-axis is 0.05

[image]

**Update:**

*Constructor*

```c#
public GeneralChart()
{
      InitializeComponent();
           
      var mapper = Mappers.Xy<ObservableDateModel>()
         .X(model => model.Date.Ticks)
         .Y(model => model.Value);

       LineSeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection(mapper);
       LineAxisYCollection = new AxesCollection();

       LineXFormatter = value => new DateTime((long)value).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
}
```

**Data for the chart above:**

```c#
 series.Values = new ChartValues<ObservableDateModel>
 {
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now, 21),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(6), 51),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), 61),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(8), 81),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), 81),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), 81),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(9), 51)
 };
```

Comment: This is completely wrong and mathematically incorrect plot. There is no 21 as value, or the plot tdoes not belong to the example code.

Comment: How do you expect your code to work if you don't initialize LineSeriesCollection and  LineAxisYCollection ? Of course your application will throw.

Answer (score 2):

Your plot is completly wrong in every aspect. Since you are not showing how you initialize your data model (the owner of the Plot()) I can't tell you what exactly went wrong. But I can tell that you are missing the data mapping to tell the chart how to plot a `ObservableDateModel`. This should be the main issue to cause the chart to plot utter garbage.

Furthermore, `LineSeries` and `Axis` are UI elements (`FrameworkElements`) that don't belong to the model. Same applies to configuring the visual appearance like colors and shapes. Always keep UI out of your data.

The following example fixes your code and shows how correctly setup a chart without mixing in the UI into your models.

The key is to use a `CartesianMapper` to tell the chart how to plot your custom model `ObservableDateModel`.

**PlotModel.cs**

```
class PlotModel : NotificationObject
{
  public PlotModel()
  {
    this.ObservableDateModelMapper = new CartesianMapper<ObservableDateModel>();
    this.ObservableDateModelMapper
      .X(item => item.Date.Ticks)
      .Y(item => item.Value);
  }

  public void Plot()
  {
    this.SeriesValues = new ChartValues<ObservableDateModel>
    {
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now, 2),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 5),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), 6),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), 8),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), 5),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5), 5),
      new ObservableDateModel(DateTime.Now.AddDays(6), 5)
    };
  }

  public CartesianMapper<ObservableDateModel> ObservableDateModelMapper { get; }
  public ChartValues<ObservableDateModel> SeriesValues { get; private set; }
  public Func<double, string> LabelFormatter => value => new DateTime((long)value).ToString();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <PloptModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <lvc:CartesianChart Height="800" 
                      LegendLocation="Right"  >
    <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
      <lvc:LineSeries Title="Bills" 
                      Configuration="{Binding ObservableDateModelMapper}" 
                      Values="{Binding SeriesValues}"
                      PointForeground="Green" 
                      Stroke="Green" />
    </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>

    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
      <lvc:Axis Title="Date" 
                LabelFormatter="{Binding LabelFormatter}" />
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
      <lvc:Axis Title="Value" 
                Foreground="Green" 
                Unit="1" />
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
  </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have updated the question to add the constructor. The implementation is done in code behind and not in the data model. The data was meant for testing. I wanted to create the chart series and axis in code behind not in XAML.